# Notification without following a user in Getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

Is there a possibility to get `notifications` from **GetStream.io APIs**, `without following` a user whom notifications are to be sent?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

User concept is inlined to a feed and for a feed to be notified, there should be an action on itself or its followings.